# Bolt on fridge missing

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

I have an Amana refrigerator with a bottom freezer. Top panel on the freezer appears to have some kind of missing bolt and will not stay closed. Any idea what exactly this is, and how I could find one to replace it? I do not even know how this is supposed to look.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Model # of the freezer? Which would let you look up parts diagrams online.

Comment: I've never known a regular domestic fridge/freezer need a bolt to stay closed. That's what the neat [squishy magnetic strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fluwO.jpg) is for. I'd be investigating what is preventing the door from closing fully.

Comment: How you find it is to either go to Amana's web site, look up your fridge model, find the drawings, identify the missing part and buy it from them, or go to any of the vast multitude of 3rd-party appliance parts sellers on line and do the same process there. Since this is basically a "where do I find a part" question, VtC as shopping, which is off-topic. The part that isn't "where do I find it" is answered by going shopping.

Comment: Nothing is supposed to be in that hole on the handle side of the door (opposite side from the hinge) except a plastic plug which is for appearance only. That hole is so the door can be reversed to hinge on the other side. If the door will not stay closed, check the side with the hinges.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the second picture, it looks like the top piece is/was being held down somewhat by tape and that there is a bolt *or something* that is supposed to hold it closer to the rest of the door. As a result, the top piece blocks proper closure.

Unfortunately, looking at [a current model](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Amana-18-cu-ft-Bottom-Freezer-Refrigerator-in-White-ABB1924BRW/204510990), and then looking up the part #, the online parts diagrams I have found show very few replaceable parts for the freezer door. The possible good news is that at least the current model is the same as a Whirlpool and a Maytag refrigerator, so parts - once you know what to get - should be very easy to find.

The doors on this model (again, the current model, yours may be a previous model but looks similar) are *reversible*. That is done by removing the doors, moving the handle (on the refrigerator part - the freezer handle is horizontal and centered so it doesn't need to be moved) and attaching to the other side. A key is that the top and bottom corners of the doors can either hold cover plates/bolts of some sort (of which one is missing) *or hinge pins*.

One definite possibility is:

- Refrigerator shipped with hinges on right side (when facing the front of the refrigerator), which matches pictures I see online for the current model.
- At installation time, the doors were reversed.
- A part was either not installed securely when moved on the top of the freezer door or was not installed at all.
- Tape to hold...but doesn't work well.

The "Use and Care Manual" at least on the current model, has some information on reversing the doors that should be useful. Not 100% clear but may be enough to figure out the missing piece. But again, that manual is specific to the particular model, so need the model # first.

Comment: Good bit of research:) I just checked my own reversible door fridge. Freezer door has a blanking plug, fridge door just has a socket [the way they're configured makes me certain there is no lost plug]. OP's issue is therefore "something is stopping the door from closing properly so the mag-strip can hold it, as designed". btw, Home Depot is geofenced, can't see it from outside NA continent.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know what is missing. But I do **not** think it is mag-strip/seal not working. The corner of the top piece is definitely too far up. There is visible tape that is not doing a good job. Might just need some super-glue. But *something* should be holding that top piece down, and with it up it blocks closing the door.

Comment: Well, yeah, as I said '*something* is stopping the mag-strip from doing its job'. The seal ought to work just fine even if you pull that bit of trim right off. It's only cosmetic. I don't think anything is 'missing' I think something's 'protruding' & I feel it's likely the trim is a red herring… as is the 'bolt'.